# Too fast executions for sorting and formatting? (VBA)

Tags: vba, performance, sorting, formatting, doevents

I am in the end of my script formatting cells (mainly interior colors depending on cell value) and sorting the rows with regards to those cells' values.

- If I run the whole script in break mode (one line at a time) it executes the procedure perfectly.
- However, when I run the whole script from start to finish without pausing the formatting and sorting does not occur.
- I have two sub procedures, one for formatting and one for sorting. If I run these again seperately after the whole code is executed they do what they are supposed to do.

The only reason I can think of is that the code is executed too fast for the amount of memory left and some commands become overwritten. I am but a VBA novice however, so please enlighten me if I am wrong.

I have tried activating `ScreenUpdating`, as well as tried to place `DoEvents` both before and after the relevant part of the code.

What are your way of handling too fast code execution? Are there other ways other than `DoEvents` to free memory inside VBA code?

---

My way of using `DoEvents` is to place `OpenForm = DoEvents` on a line where I think the local queue might need to be processed, or together with an If statement and `Mod` inside for loops.

My sorting code looks like this (The variable *ws* is the worksheet):

```
'Sort rows
    With ws.Range("AE2").CurrentRegion
            On Error Resume Next
        .Sort.SortFields.Clear
            On Error GoTo 0
        .Cells.Sort Key1:=Range(ws.Cells(2, 33), ws.Cells(LastRow, 33)), Order1:=xlDescending, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, Header:=xlYes
    End With
```

My formatting code is too long and probably not relevant. But it is basically made up of If statements and interior coloring, eg.

```
If AbsVal < 3 And AbsVal >= 1 Then DiffCell.Interior.Color = vbRed
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faced the same problem myself a few weeks back, I found the solution for it in some forum which sadly I don't remember. Credits go to unknown
However, I have the code and it works fine:

```
Sub Sort()
'Sorting code
Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue(a few seconds depending on your choice, pre), " Color "
End Sub


Sub Color()
'coloring code
Exit Sub
```